# поле и кнопка пропадают при нажатии

Tags: javascript

как сделать чтобы хекс код и сам цвет отображались под полем после нажатия?после нажатия поле и кнопка пропадают

```js
function myFunction() { 
 var x =  document.getElementById("myText").value;
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
 switch (x) {
 case "red":
  document.write("#FF0000" + "<div style='width:100px;height:50px;background:red'></div>");
  break;
 case "RED":
  document.write("#FF0000" + "<div style='width:100px;height:50px;background:red'></div>");
  break;
 case "black":
  document.write("#000000" + "<div style='width:100px;height:50px;background:black'></div>");
  break;
 case "BLACK":
  document.write("#000000" + "<div style='width:100px;height:50px;background:black'></div>");
  break;
 case "pink":
  document.write("#FFC0CB" + "<div style='width:100px;height:50px;background:pink'></div>");
  break;
 case "PINK":
  document.write("#FFC0CB" + "<div style='width:100px;height:50px;background:pink'></div>");
  break;
 case "yellow":
  document.write("#FFFF00") + "<div style='width:100px;height:50px;background:yellow'></div>";
  break;
 case "YELLOW":
  document.write("#FFFF00") + "<div style='width:100px;height:50px;background:yellow'></div>";
  break;
 default:
  document.write("please insert a color name");

}
        }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="myText">
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()"> 
  Try  it 
  </button> 
    <p id="demo"></p> 

    <script src="script.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Замените `document.write` на `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ...`

Comment: И никогда не используйте `document.write` - он ломает верстку. Это уже очень устаревший способ

Answer (score 1):

Можно решить таким способом. Но вообще, есть алгоритмы, которые преобразуют rgb в hex. С ними вы сможете вывести hex значения любого цвета без хардкода.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const colors = {
    red: '#FF0000',
    black: '#000000',
    pink: '#FFC0CB',
    yellow: 'yellow'
  };
  const x = document.getElementById("myText").value.toLowerCase();
  const demo = document.getElementById("demo");
  if (colors[x]) {
    demo.innerHTML = colors[x] + "<div style='width:100px;height:50px;background:" + x + "'></div>";
  } else {
    demo.innerHTML = "please insert a color name";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myText">
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try  it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
          function myFunction() { 
  var x =  document.getElementById("myText").value;




  switch (x) {
  case "red":
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ("#FF0000" + "<div style='width:100px;height:50px;background:red'></div>");
    break;
  case "RED":
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =("#FF0000" + "<div style='width:100px;height:50px;background:red'></div>");
    break;
  case "black":
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =("#000000" + "<div style='width:100px;height:50px;background:black'></div>");
    break;
  case "BLACK":
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =("#000000" + "<div style='width:100px;height:50px;background:black'></div>");
    break;
  case "pink":
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =("#FFC0CB" + "<div style='width:100px;height:50px;background:pink'></div>");
    break;
  case "PINK":
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =("#FFC0CB" + "<div style='width:100px;height:50px;background:pink'></div>");
    break;
  case "yellow":
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =("#FFFF00") + "<div style='width:100px;height:50px;background:yellow'></div>";
    break;
  case "YELLOW":
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =("#FFFF00") + "<div style='width:100px;height:50px;background:yellow'></div>";
    break;
  default:
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =("please insert a color name");

}
        }
```

Comment: Вам самому нравится, как выглядит ваш ответ?

Comment: нет но показал как изменить уже существующий код